# Kafka Consumer: How To Catch Failover Of Brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently trying to design a Kafka failover system to detect when a Kafka cluster (broker) goes down, but I'm having trouble getting the Consumer to realize that the broker is down.

I see that a Consumer will continuously poll if there is no data (while it is still connected to the broker) but if the broker goes down, my Consumer just sits there doing nothing forever.

Is there a property somewhere that I need to set for it to raise an Exception or something if it is unable to communicate with the broker? Or do I need to utilize some sort of a callback?

Thanks!

Comment: Behavior of the consumer on broker failure is sadly not a trivial topic, its been on my list of 'stuff to properly investigate' for a long time, but I have not gotten around to it yet. You can start with [KAFKA-1894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1894) and look at the related jiras as well, that might give you a decent idea. But ultimately I think the answer at this time is that you will have to implement some sort of background thread that checks for a timeout and kills the consumer when it is reached yourself if you want this behavior.

Comment: @SönkeLiebau Yeah I did quite a bit of searching around (browsing through source code too) and it seems like currently that is the only approach that will work. The consumer just blocks indefinitely until it can reconnect or is terminated. I will investigate and see if the wakeup() call from another thread can properly shut down the consumer in such case. Thanks!